# iOS/Google Ads giving Linker Code Failure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Trying to insert Google Ads/Firebase into a test app. Suspect I've almost got this working but. Using the Google notes from https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

When I compile I receive "Linker code failed with exit code 1":

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/edward/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TotalConversion-gtwxqoywudjqpodqkpfpwcnovyuz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have created the Podfile as instructed with:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, ’7.0’

target 'TotalConversion' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end
```

and then run a pod update. I don't see a .xcworkspace file referred to in the docs. Does the iOS, '7.0' line above need to be altered?

I presume that using pods GoogleAds is instead of the standard framework (Build Phases/Link Binary) approach.

Comment: Did you try updating cocoapods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a linker error, this might be few things. First, check if you haven't open .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace by mistake. If not, the solution might be simple project cleaning by pressing cmd+shift+k. At last, check if those libraries are linked with project and are having status required in your target's general/build phases (Pods_YourProjectName.framework).

In Podfile you can actually comment out lines with source and platform by placing # in front of them. Go to terminal, `cd` to your project directory and try `pod install` once again, maybe that will do the job.

Sorry for not placing this in comments but my reputation doesn't allow me doing it.

Comment: Don't apologies that was a very comprehensive answer. Have removed all the GoogleAdd components and the error has evaporated, so at least this confirms the culprit. Will reinstall slowly and report back. Many thanks.

Comment: According to other posts there is an issue using TextEdit, which I was and I did have "smart quotes" turned off. I have removed the pods, deleted all offending files and reinstalled the software according to the Google notes, but get EXACTLY the same error again. Need to look for another way to install this or find another Ad system...

Comment: There is an entry from over a year ago called "Xcode 7 build failed due to ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices" which describes exactly my issue. I have tried to effect these changes with no joy and suspect it requires a complete cleanup and reinstall. WHY can't large organisations check their code and make sure it just works.

Comment: The ads aren't appearing but the bug has been removed. Google use different names from what they put in the build phases and you have to edit them manually so they are one and the same - why???

Comment: Hah, they probably just thought programmer's life will be way too easy if they won't make few bugs, so there they are :)

Answer (score 1):

The {projectName}.xcworkspace folder should be in the same folder as the .xcodeproj that you have open. Close Xcode {projectName}.xcodeproj instance and open {projectName}.xcworkspace using the Finder, command line, or Xcode open.

Comment: Found it - what should be in it out of interest?

Comment: It's a combined workspace for building and linking your project along with its dependent Cocapods.